# Lifespan of NSTimers with ARC

Tags: ios, objective-c, timer

Say I have a view controller.

In my view controller, I schedule a method to be called from some other class every 9 seconds:

```
   redTimer=[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:9 target:appDelegate.koule selector:@selector(fbWander) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

I have a few questions about this.

What if I did not assign my instance variable redTimer to the returned NSTimer. What would happen? Would the method get called every 9 seconds forever?

Now, since I have assigned redTimer to the timer, what happens if redTimer is assigned a different timer (and thus nothing would be referring to my original timer anymore) would the timer die and stop repeating?

What if I assign it to redTimer and then my view controller is destroyed... will that stop the method from being called every 9 seconds?

What happens to the timer and its action in these cases?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With ARC, somebody needs to have a strong reference to an object at all times or it gets released and deallocated.

In the case of scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats:, the timer gets created and then immediately added to the current run loop. The runloop retains it. If repeats is set to YES, the timer is kept alive. If the timer is set to repeats=NO, it is kept alive until it is done firing (Until the timer's selector finishes executing). Once that happens the runloop releases it, it's retain count drops to zero, and it gets deallocated.

If the timer is repeating, then it will be retained by the runloop until you invalidate it. Then it gets released.

If you save your timer to a strong instance variable, the instance variable also maintains a strong reference, so the timer's reference counter won't drop to zero until you nil out the strong reference.

Comment: For repeating timers that I create using scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval... I tend to set them up as weak instance variables (or properties). Then, when I want to stop the timer, I just use code like `[myTimer invalidate];`. That causes the runloop to release the timer. It gets deallocated, and then the system zeros my weak reference. If I then try to send the timer a second invalidate message, the weak iVar is now nil, so the call doesn't do anything. That means I don't need to both invalidate and set the timer to nil, and I can send an invalidate w/o making sure the timer is running.